# How to use telethon session file to login with pyrogram

Tags: python, session, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

After logging in to my telegram account with `Telethon` it generates a `.session` file. I need to use that file to login to the same account but with `Pyrogram` instead of telethon.

But telethon and pyrogram sessions files have different structures and pyrogram doesn't support telethon session files and vice-versa. The same thing applies on session strings.

How can I login using `Pyrogram` to an account that is already logged in to Telegram using `Telethon` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool that solved my problem
https://github.com/HKPROJECTS/session-conv-bot

it converts `Telethon` session file to a `Pyrogram` session file